# CsipSimple on Galaxy SIII

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, pjsip, csip-simple

I succesfully customized CSipSimple and built a SIP based app. I have tested the app on more than 10 devices. Every thing is fine. App doesn't run on Samsung Galaxy SIII. Sip doesn't get registered. It shows no error nothing is shown in Logcat. What would be the problem? Have anyone customized CSipSimple? If yes, is it running on Galaxy SIII?

P.S. I even observed that the original CSipSimple app isn't working on SIII.

Comment: Hi Did you implemented TLS in this application how do you configure it's setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. I was doing some network operation on the UI thread. Using Async Task solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

see regis' post here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/csipsimple-users/p7dzp189QN4

no guarantee that it's what you're looking for